# Programmatically moving file between Blob folders not actually working

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions, azure-blob-storage

I'm working on my first Azure Function to process a file. As part of that I'm trying to move a file from one folder to another inside of a Blob Storage account.
I found some code and tweaked it for my situation and it looks as though it's running successfully without any errors but the files aren't actually getting moved.

I have a Blob storage with an Input, Output, and Processed folder. I will be picking up a file from input, processing it, and then I want to move it to the processed folder.
It seems as though I have to actually copy the file from the input to the output folder and then delete out the file from the input folder. I have the following code to do so
and it runs without any errors now. However, afterwards the files don't actually get moved. During debugging I can see the blob URI and everything looks correct there.

Any ideas on what I need to do?

```
private async Task MoveFileAsync(string sourceFolder, string destinationFolder, string fileName, ILogger log)
{
    log.LogInformation("Moving file. Source: {0}  | Destination: {1} | FileName: {2}.", sourceFolder, destinationFolder, fileName);

    try
    {
        var sourceConnection = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("StorageConnection");

        // Create connection to storage account.
        BlobServiceClient sourceClient = new BlobServiceClient(sourceConnection);

        BlobContainerClient sourceContainer = sourceClient.GetBlobContainerClient(sourceFolder);
        BlobContainerClient destinationContainer = sourceClient.GetBlobContainerClient(destinationFolder); 

        // Get blob for specific file in storage.
        BlobClient sourceBlob = sourceContainer.GetBlobClient(fileName);

        BlobClient destBlob = destinationContainer.GetBlobClient(sourceBlob.Name);

        // Create a API Uri to the source file name
        var blobUri = new Uri($"{sourceContainer.Uri}/{sourceBlob.Name}");
        CopyFromUriOperation ops = await destBlob.StartCopyFromUriAsync(blobUri);

        //delete source file
        await sourceBlob.DeleteAsync();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        log.LogError("Error moving file. {0} | {1} | {2}", ex.Message, ex.StackTrace, ex.InnerException);
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: By `Folder`, you mean Blob Container. Right?

Comment: No, I have folders inside of a blob container.

Comment: Unrelated: `await sourceBlob.DeleteAsync();` - I personally would confirm and double confirm, that the copy has been successful, before deleting the source.

Comment: Can you share an example of input values you are passing to your method? Also, do you see anything in the logs?

Comment: Do mind that `StartCopyFromUriAsync` only **starts**  the operation. Since it therefore is not guaranteed that the operation is completed before you delete the source blob you might run into trouble. Check the logs

Comment: I'll change up some of the code to check that it's complete before deleting. I added a picture to the original post that shows the URI to the correct folder structure and file.